# Lengthen an edge infinitely (a.k.a. vanishing point)

Tags: camera, edges

I'm using Blender to make 2D perspective drawing materials for educational purposes. I'd like to demonstrate how the vanishing points change along with the camera angle. I know how to animate the camera, but to show the vanishing points of a cube I need to extend its edges to infinitely.

[image]

How can I emulate this effect in Blender (preferably in EEVEE)?

Comment: Is this for a static render or do you need to be able to move around and see the same effect?

Comment: @TheTrueJard Being able to move around and demo in Blender would be the best. But if it's impossible I think it's okay to render an animation.

Comment: Blender can’t handle truly infinite values, the best I can think of would be to create the lines as a mesh and scale them up until they’re past the clipping point of the camera. They won’t actually intersect at a point but they’ll come very close to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your screen resolution is far from infinite, moving points far away will quickly reach the pixel size of your display. Starting with a 2m default cube, extruding an edge back 5000m should be plenty enough to simulate infinity and have them join at a subpixel level. Before doing this, don't forget to increase the `Clip End` limit of your viewport of camera.

Here is a simple way to do it in the view port:

[image]

Comment: It's a little beyond the scope of the original question, but when I tried this the edges look very thin, practically invisible on larger displays. I tried to add a wireframe modifier but it only applies to the cube, not the extruded parts.

Comment: OK, skin modifier does the trick. It's not perfect but good enough for the demonstration.

Comment: If you want the `wireframe modifier` to work, you have to keep a face for some reason.